# Mergin threads by treebased pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, quicksort

I have a task where I need to sort an array by quicksort algorithm. Size of array and amount of threads can be custom. Also I've have to merge threads like on picture: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPb3P.png)
As I understood I need to split an array by amount of proccessors and sorted it.

```
class Quicksort implements Callable<int[]>{
int[] arr;

Quicksort(int[] array){
    this.arr = array;
}
@Override
public int[] call() throws Exception {
     sort(arr,0,arr.length-1);
    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    return arr;
}

/* This function takes last element as pivot,
       places the pivot element at its correct
       position in sorted array, and places all
       smaller (smaller than pivot) to left of
       pivot and all greater elements to right
       of pivot */
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = (low-1); // index of smaller element
    for (int j=low; j<high; j++)
    {
        // If current element is smaller than or
        // equal to pivot
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;

            // swap arr[i] and arr[j]
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    // swap arr[i+1] and arr[high] (or pivot)
    int temp = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;

    return i+1;
}


/* The main function that implements QuickSort()
  arr[] --> Array to be sorted,
  low  --> Starting index,
  high  --> Ending index */
void sort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[pi] is
          now at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        // Recursively sort elements before
        // partition and after partition
        sort(arr, low, pi-1);
        sort(arr, pi+1, high);
    }
}
```

In Main class I'm using ExecutorService to do sorting stuff

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

 List<int[]> chunckedList = Utils.covertFrom2DToList(chuncked);


    try {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        List<Quicksort> callableList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int[] chunck : chunckedList) {
            callableList.add(new Quicksort(chunck));
        }

        List<Future<int[]>> futureObjects = executorService.invokeAll(callableList);
        executorService.shutdown();


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to merge it in threads.
Could you give me a hint or advice how to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: You may wish to look into a `ForkJoinPool`, if your instructor will allow it.

Comment: Yeah, but i wish to understand concurrency principles. But if it will be too hard I'll take a look. Ty